# How can I pass a text string from an mpi4py worker process back to root = 0 for writing to text output

Tags: python, numpy, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to pass a text string which contains information about the progress of worker processes back to root = 0. I am using `comm.recv`, however, I cannot receive the list containing the text as I get the error `TypeError: expected a writeable buffer object`.

The MWE I am trying to set up is below:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
from mpi4py.MPI import ANY_SOURCE
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()


data = []
recv_buffer = []


for i in range(0,10,1):
    data = data + ["Logfile for iteration %s on rank %s" %(i,rank)]

print(rank)
print(data)

if rank == 0:
        output = data[0]
        for i in range(1, size):
                comm.recv(recv_buffer,ANY_SOURCE)
                output += recv_buffer[0]
else:
        # all other process send their result
        comm.send(data)


if rank == 0:
    print(output)
```

This fails at the line `comm.recv(recv_buffer,ANY_SOURCE)`. `recv_buffer` is pre-specified as `recv_buffer = []`. How can I make this writeable?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to provide a buffer when using the *lower-case* interface. You can simply omit the buffer parameter and take the return value:

```
if rank == 0:
    output = data # Note, removed data[0], otherwise it is not a list
    for i in range(1, size):
        recv_buffer = comm.recv(source=ANY_SOURCE)
        output += recv_buffer
```

Note, it is much better - and easier - to use a collective operation here.

```
import itertools

# No separate send/recv, just this single line
output = comm.gather(data, root=0)
# on rank 0, output will be a list of lists
if rank == 0:
    # You can convert it to a flat list
    # If you iterate over the output, you can omit the list(), just use the chain.
    output = list(itertools.chain(*output))
    print(output)
```

Comment: I've been looking at `numpy` arrays already. But I can't easily receive text into a numpy array. Why is it not possible to do this with a list? `data = []` appears to be writeable in my example so I'm not sure why this isn't writeable for `recv_buffer`.

Comment: I have misread your question, please see my updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @218, note that I am assuming you want a list of all log entries among all processes. Is there any reason your code us using `data[0]`? That way you would only make a string containing all of the first log entries among the processes.